# How to catch routes in *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

So I want to make an anchor element on my Header disappear when a specific page is hit. How can I catch the url in the `*ngIf` when that page is hit.

I have a header which will remain same for all pages. Just need to hide an anchor element when I am routed at `/home`. How to catch this `"/home"` in `*ngIf`?

`*ngIf = "href='/home'"` is not working. Any alternatives?

Comment: Try *ngIf="[routerLinkActive]=="'/home'";  not tested

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*mycomponent.component.ts*

```js
import { Router } from '@angular/router'

class MyComponent {
    constructor(public router: Router) { }
}
```

*mycomponent.component.html*

```html
<div *ngIf="router.url === '/some/route'">
    <!-- … -->
</div>
```

Comment: Attention, `router` must be `public` instead of `private`, please update your answer.

Comment: This answer is WRONG. router must be public.

Answer (score 9):

I came to this page because I had the same issue than Ravy but the proposed solutions were not ok for me.

The accepted answer is not working if you are using route path with query params.

Here's the solution I use:

*mycomponent.component.ts*

```js
import { Router } from '@angular/router'

class MyComponent {
    constructor(public router: Router) { }
}
```

*mycomponent.component.html*

```html
<div *ngIf="router.isActive('/some/route')">
    <!-- … -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular version 17, proceed as follows:

- add CommonModule to the Imports Array (This is for *ngIf)
- add public Router to the constructor

`mycomponent.component.ts`:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrl: './footer.component.scss'
})
export class FooterComponent {
  constructor(public router: Router) {

  }
}
```

`mycomponent.component.html`:

```
<div *ngIf="router.url === '/yourRoute'">
    
</div>
```

You can now use `router.url` in the template and query your current route.

Answer (score -3):

// mycomponent.component.ts

```
class MyComponent {
    constructor(public router: Router){

    }
}
```

// mycomponent.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="this.router.url === '/some/route'">

</div>
```

Comment: Not needed to use `this` on your template filem just `router.url`